# Sorting Product Collection by MulitSelect Attribute

Tags: category, product-collection

My client wants me to sort a category of products where the products with a particular mutli-select attribute `lumen_style_icons` option `NEW` selected will show first.

I am assuming there is no way to push these products to the front of a collection, If you know of a way to do that, that would be great.

I am trying to just create two collections, one that contains only the products with the `NEW` selected, and the other collection with all the products in the category.

I am having a problem getting "finset" to work

Here is my code:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$newProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId())
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('lumen_style_icons', array('finset' => 'NEW'));
```

I am getting a count of 0 for `$newProductCollection`

-Thanks

Comment: I believe you will need the option ID of `NEW`, instead of the option value.

Comment: How would you find that?